# Iperf Tcp Client and Server

Tags: tcp, iperf

I'd really like to know why the bandwith in the client is higher than the server, i can´t find the answer explaining why this happens.

Thank you,
Tiago Melancia

Values of the bandwidth:
[Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyYZv.png) 
[Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzt51.png)